# is it possible to pass a value using javascript onclick listerner for various items in a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am having a challenge below with javascipt in combination with php including html forms.

On clicking the link, it submits only one value from the loop. i.e the first value from the while loop.

a screenshot of the result is provided here [link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR4Hp.jpg).

from the above , when i click on any other link it just retrns the first one.

what i need is that the link to post values based on each link clicked. my code is here.

```
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $client_name = $row["client_name"]; 

                echo "<form id='form_submit' action='index.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='name'  value='$client_name'/>
                        <a href='#' onclick='submitForm(name)'>$client_name</a>
                    </form>
                 <script>

                    function submitForm(name) {
                    let form = document.getElementById('form_submit')
                    form.submit()
                        }
                </script><br>"; 
                
    }
    $result->free();
} else
echo "no records found";
```

the form is designed to submitt to the same page where it is captured by other php file which checks if a value is posted and proceed with some execution from there,

the receiving php file queries data from the databse based on the values submitted by the link clicked,

which in this case the link clicked only submits the value for the first item.

Comment: you can’t have duplicate `id`. but sure there are many ways to do this. hint: you don’t need a separate `function` for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that in a cleaner manner with a single `form` rather than a potentially large number. There is no need to use ID attributes for every element which is what was causing the original issue - rely upon the event target to indicate which element/link was clicked or, as here, use `this` from within the callback.

```
<form name='clients' method='post' action='index.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='name' />

<?php

    if( $result = $conn->query($query) ) {
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            printf( '<a href="#">%s</a>', $row["client_name"] );
        }
        $result->free();
        
    } else {
        echo "no records found";
    }
?>
</form>
<script>

    const oForm=document.forms.clients;
    const oInput=oForm.name;
    
    oForm.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a=>{
        a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            oInput.value=this.textContent;
            oForm.submit();
        })
    })
</script>
```

For the sake of completeness in light of the comment regarding a single event listener as opposed to one bound to each hyperlink. With this event bubbling is what makes it work. A common ancestor has the event listener bound to it ( the form ) and the `event.target` is inspected to find which element actually triggered the event. This does avoid multiple duplicate event listeners.

```
const oForm=document.forms.clients;
const oInput=oForm.name;

oForm.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement ){
        oInput.value=e.target.textContent;
        oForm.submit();     
    }
})
```

Further reading about [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) & [Event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Comment: thank you so much , it really worked. I had to add a line break inside the loop to arrange  items in a list format.

Comment: Rather than adding a `<br />` within the loop or whatever you did you could use CSS to arrange the hyperlinks on different rows but I'm glad that it helped

Comment: you could also use a single event listener on the form :)

Comment: The single listener ( delegated ) would be more complicted for a beginner to understand I feel when inspecting the event.target/currentTarget and identifying the element etc but sure, could easily be done.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius as i was using the same code for the second accordion, it did not work.... or should i just rewrite another question? the first accordion is working fine, the one posted as a question

Comment: I can not see any reference to accordions in the above so it is a little unclear what you mean

Comment: <script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
     if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
         } else {
          panel.style.display = "block";
           }
        });
      }
 </script>    this is the script for accordion for all the accordions... so the thing is that it works with the first accordion only... but the second accordion is not submitting anything

Comment: As per the comment made before by @Mulan and addressed in the amended answer- rather than assign the same listener to potentially hundreds of elements (number unknown) you can use `event delegation` and assign the listener to a common ancestor element?!

Comment: The snippet you added in a comment has no supporting HTML structure to work with. You might be better asking a new question as it is fundamentally different to this question

Comment: okay... [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349051/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-value-for-various-accordion-in-a-web-side-nav-bar) @ProfessorAbronsius